# Cleanest way of joining a dictionary to a string?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have

```
k: `a`b`c
v: 1 2 3
```

How can we make a string of the form:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lambda accomplishes what you want (accepting a dictionary as its argument):

```
{"&" sv "=" sv/: string flip (key;value)@\:x} `a`b`c!1 2 3
```

Comment: And because `"="` is an atom, `/:` can be `'`, i.e. `"&"sv"="sv'string flip(key;value)@\:`a`b`c!1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

This is very situational but if you're only doing this for "display" purposes then you could make use of built-in `.Q.s`

```
q)ssr/[-2_.Q.s d;("| ";"\r\n");("=";"&")]
"a=1&b=2&c=3"
```

The output would be limited by your console size though, so for all practical purposes you would/should use kylebonnes answer.

EDIT: `.Q.s2` gets you pretty close too:

```
q)"&"sv"="^.Q.s2 d
"a|=1&b|=2&c|=3"
```

EDIT2: based on your further disclosure that the purpose of this is to build query strings then I've a few other comments:

1. You most likely want commas `,` instead of `&` then. You shouldn't normally use `&` in where clauses in queries.
2. Neither mine nor kylebonnes solution would work for you in the event that you had symbols in the values of your dictionary, e.g.

```
d:`a`b`c!`one`two`three
```

and you're trying to build a query that says

```
where a=`one,b=`two,c=`three
```

in this case you'd have to try to use maybe `.Q.s1` or else have logic to put the backticks in place.

3. An alternative might be to build a functional form of a query but you're still going to be faced with similar problems

```
q)"?[t;",(-3!{(=;x;d x)}each key d),";0b;()]"
"?[t;((=;`a;1);(=;`b;2);(=;`c;3));0b;()]"
```

4. Ultimately it isn't really good practice to be manufacturing complex query strings to send to a kdb server. Can you wrap your desired query up into a function and define the function on the server? Then your URL just has to call the function. Why can't you send a direct synchronous call to the kdb server, e.g.

```
h:hopen`::1234;
h({<function to generate query without having to string>};`a`b`c!1 2 3)
```

Comment: The objective is to make URL querystrings out of dictionaries; I'm not sure KDB has such a utility built-in?